# Is it possible to pass a stringstream as a function parameter?

Tags: c++, function, parameter-passing, stringstream

Is it possible to pass in a stringstream and have the function write to it directly?

I remember I saw a function invoked similar to something like this:

```
my_func(ss << "text" << hex << 33);
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Sure thing. Why wouldn't it be? Example declaration of such function:

```
void my_func(std::ostringstream& ss);
```

Comment: thank you, that what I missed, I knew it is somewhat possible but I didn't know what declaration use to achieve that effect

Comment: Except that the type of `ss << "test" << hex << 33` is not `std::stringstream&`, but `std::ostream&`, and that won't match the given signature.

Comment: @JamesKanze for some reason, compiler does not complain, see GDB online https://onlinegdb.com/2FgGiOBfHw

Comment: However, still wondering why not using `stringstream` instead of `ostream`...

Answer (score 12):

Absolutely! Make sure that you pass it by reference, not by value.

```
void my_func(ostream& stream) {
    stream << "Hello!";
}
```

Comment: why should it be passed by reference only?

Comment: @aderchox Otherwise it would not compile (streams have no copy constructor).

Answer (score 5):

`my_func` has to have a signature along the lines of:

```
void my_func( std::ostream& s );
```

, since that's the type of `ss << "text" << hex << 33`.  If the goal is
to extract the generated string, you'ld have to do something like:

```
void
my_func( std::ostream& s )
{
    std::string data = dynamic_cast<std::ostringstream&>(s).str();
    //  ...
}
```

Note too that you can't use a temporary stream;

```
my_func( std::ostringstream() << "text" << hex << 33 );
```

won't compile (except maybe with VC++), since it's not legal C++.  You
could write something like:

```
my_func( std::ostringstream().flush() << "text" << hex << 33 );
```

if you wanted to use a temporary.  But that's not very user friendly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is, and

```
Function(expresion)
```

Will make the expression to be evaluated first and the result of it will be passed as a parameter

Note: [Operator << for ostreams](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/) returns a ostream